# How to set ticks in chart js as per in picture

Tags: chart.js

[image: chart]

Sample Images for ticks in chart js

Now I am trying to set tick as like image attached.
I am using chart js.

In my personal project, I have to set the chart ticks as per image.
I have tried, but it is out of my reach.

Comment: how to set ticks in chart js like -0,-20,-40,-60,-80,100,80,60,40,20,0

Comment: don't know if [this link](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/radial/linear.html#step-size) may help you